# Pillow installed correctly but Image Field got error Pillow is not installed - Django

Tags: django, pip, python-imaging-library

I install correctly Pillow using all these comments: Pip install Pillow - Pip Insall Pillow==6.2.0 -

```
pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (7.2.0)
```

python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow

```
python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
Requirement already up-to-date: Pillow in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (7.2.0)
```

And update Pip as successfully, but when I want to add ImageField
like this: `image = models.ImageField()`, I've got this error:

```
eCommerce.Item.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run the command "pip install Pillow".
```

> some people say this is for the version of your windows but I install pip
> for win64

please help, thank you

Comment: how did you call your manage.py? maybe you link to the wrong python version?

Comment: @Tobit  , python manage.py runserver like this.

Comment: @Tobit maybe you link to the wrong python version? / how can I Check it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you call manage.py using:

```
python manage.py runserver

python3.7 manage.py runserver
```

or something similar try installing pillow using

```
python -m pip install pillow==6.2.0
```

this will install it into the targeted version, make sure to replace `python` with whichever command you used to run manage.py, like `python3.8` or similar.

Hope this would help!

Comment: im run this comment : this is result :  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Include\pillow' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Please let us know the exact command you used.Try: `python3.8  - m pip install pillow==6.2.0`. If this command succeeded you should be able to import pillow in python3.8, else post the error log, here.